# windows xp, "lost" memory in c:\windows folder

Tags: windows-xp, storage

I'm running windows xp on this laptop, and experiencing something "weird".

My  (minor, system) hard drive was once again getting full again. (it's a 30 GB drive). So I started to look into where the data is stored. I see 7 GB in the documents & settings folder, and 12 GB in the windows folder (c:\windows).

Now I just went to check the windows folder (not that I would change anything there), and notice something: when selecting all files and folders, and clicking on  "properties" **it only reports 8 GB**

So I lost 4 gb somewhere? What can cause this? And yes I've setted windows to show hidden folders & system folders.

On an unrelated note: have you guys also experienced a strange influx of programs which write huge amounts of data to the %appdata% directory instead of where they are installed? Strange.

Comment: Applications are **suppose** to write to %appdata% **not** to where they are installed.  The strange influx is because for these are not allowed to write to where they are installed under Vista and 7.  Besides, it is a huge security risk.

Comment: And here's me thinking making sure applications are run on a seperate physical disk would make things more secure ><. I always thought appdata was just for settings & maybe documents. But now I see applications completely copy themselves there. (or at least updates/service packs of themself end up there). - Anyways I guess I'll port that folder my other drive, but that wasnt'the main problem :P, thanks though.

Comment: Yeah, it's a side effect of Windows being a multi user OS, so temporary files used under one user could conflict with temporary files if another user decides to log into the same computer.

Comment: Just get a bigger drive.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not going to join the bandwagon of buying stuff constantly: I bought this laptop 6 years ago. It worked back then, I don't have higher needs than 6 years ago, it hasn't broken. So why buy something new - just cause some guy needs to fill his economic pocket?

Comment: not an answer per say but you could use [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) to pinpoint where space is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Folder properties and selecting files and folders is different. When looking at folder properties (from right click properties) it will give you the total amount in the folder and sub-folders. When using "selecting all files and folders" it does not typically include hidden and system files unless your system is setup to do so. That is likely the reason you see a difference.

Comment: well I manually selected all files I could see inside the folder. As said I setted the folder options already to show hidden files & systemfiles.

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood your description properly, it.

Formatting of a disk takes space, normally about the amount you are suggesting.

What is how if you get an iPod say, it's 8GB you only get about 6.8 usable, as the formatting is taking up space.

Alternatively try running CCleaner.

Comment: Well in windows the index files etc aren't shown when looking to the space of a disk. And especially now when I open a folder, and check the amount of data inside that folder. - Also the difference between 8GB on the box & 6.8 in reality, might be caused by the company counting 1000 bytes in a kilobyte :P